# Maven failing to transfer artifact to/from + Access denied: ReasonPhrase:Forbidden

Tags: java, maven, nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to build my application in Maven in a large enterprise setting (internal support is out of ideas, hence I'm carrying it to a wider audience).

We're using a Sonatype Nexus repository to either proxy or host all plugins/dependencies and upon executing `mvn clean install` I get the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) on project <redacted>: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:3.3.1 -> org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.26: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.26: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:pom:1.26 from/to nexus (http://<redacted.tld>/repository/maven/): Access denied to: http://<redacted.tld>/repository/maven/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.26/plexus-interpolation-1.26.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]`

What left me puzzled is that according to our Nexus Team, the access is anonymous, hence no login is required. Also if I just *wget* the package with the link from the UI is works perfectly fine. Any SO answer I managed to find so far either describes how to properly enter user and password in the *~/.m2/settings.xml* - which in my case is even not required at all - or is related to uploading an artifact into the repository. The other packages in my project seem to download just fine, so the proxy config *generally* appears to be working.

I'm using Maven 3.5.2 on Amazon Linux 2 (EC2@AWS), Coretto 17.0.8 LTS and Nexus Repository Pro 3.44.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Upgrade to 3.8.8+

Comment: maven or sonatype nexus?

Comment: I updated to maven 3.9.4 which didn't solve my issue. In case you meant nexus, this is nothing I could so, since it's managed by a different department. Any other idea maybe?

Comment: I see nothing with this response of the Nexus server is configured to the repo sharding/partitioning. You might want to consider to try https://maven.apache.org/resolver/remote-repository-filtering.html to reduce the request count.